# Preloading photos in a Facebook album

Tags: facebook, photos, album

Is it possible to preload the rest of a Facebook photo album as I view the photos?

I don't want to have to wait for each photo to load and sit there as it fetches the next image as I navigate through the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook preloads the previous and the next two photos in the album.

[image: Next two images loaded]